# setText textview с помощью radiobutton

Tags: java, android

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView = (TextView)  findViewById(R.id.textView);
    radioGroup= (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);
    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            // checkedId is the RadioButton selected
            RadioButton radioButton_250=(RadioButton)findViewById(checkedId);
            textView.setText(radioButton_250.getText());
            RadioButton radioButton_500=(RadioButton)findViewById(checkedId);
            textView.setText(radioButton_500.setText("70"));

        }
    });
}
```

Первая кнопка, которая вытягивает текст работает нормально, а вот вторая `textView.setText(radioButton_500.setText("70"));` не пускает, как можно это быстренько исправить?

Comment: а что должно быть в итоге?

Comment: вторая кнопка должна просто задавать значение, в данном случае 70

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Строка

> textView.setText(radioButton_500.setText("70"));

Не должна компилироваться, т.к. метод setText() требует String в качестве аргумента, а результат вызова `radioButton_500.setText("70")` возвращает `void`.

Если вам надо поменять текст в radioButton и потом назначить его куда-то, то делайте по очереди:

```
radioButton_500.setText("70");
textView.setText(radioButton_500.getText());
```

---

Для смены теста по нажатию на RadioButtom в RadioGroup вам надо сделать как-то так:

```
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        // checkedId is the RadioButton selected
        //RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) group.findViewById(checkedId);
        //textView.setText(radioButton.getText());
        switch(checkedId)
        {
            case R.id.someID:
                //тут нужный текст установите
                break;
            case R.id.anotherID:
                //тут нужный текст установите
                break;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: фишка как раз в том, что текст самой radiobutton не должен задаваться а лишь в textview, Вы говорите стринговое значение в качестве аргумента, textView.setText(radioButton_500.setText(R.string.r_500)); это на подобе этого?)

Comment: @Romikromikromik так может вам надо textView.setText("70")? Просто вы пишете абсурдные вещи

Comment: @АндроидАндроид. Ну вам, как профи они кажутся абсурдными, а я как начинающий, конечно плохо знаю семантику.  Если делать как вы говорите, вот так RadioButton radioButton_250=(RadioButton)findViewById(checkedId);
                textView.setText("69");
                RadioButton radioButton_500=(RadioButton)findViewById(checkedId);
                textView.setText("80"); , то в textview ставится лишь последнее значение (80), и оно не меняется. Так как переменная radiobutton_500 и radiobutton_250 в textview.setText**** не указана

Comment: @Romikromikromik, т.е. вам надо по нажатию на один из RadioButton поменять текст в TextView?...

Comment: @ЮрийСПб да, именно это

Comment: @Romikromikromik, дополнил ответ. Вы в самом деле что-то очень странное пытались в коде сделать)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб , блин)), смотрите Вы мне написали textView.setText(radioButton.getText()); логика этой команды заключается в вытягивании текста из radiobutton и установке его же, этого текста, в textview. НО НУЖНО установить текст которого в radiobutton нет, совершенно другой, пусть radiobutton называется 250,  а textview должен быть 777 )) название radiobutton трогать не нужно))

Comment: @Romikromikromik, я ещё раз обновил ответ. Но почему вы удивляетесь, что вас неверно понимают если вы изначально не пишите чего как и почему вы хотите добиться?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб извините, в следующий раз постараюсь максимально четко описывать задачу,а не заниматься кучей лишних дел. Спасибо.